# No cookies being sent by the browser even when they have not expired

Tags: asp.net, cookies

This is a weird issue that I am facing while forms authentication. 
I am using google chrome.
After a user has been authenticated, a cookie is saved on the client's machine. Currently the expiry date is 1 day ahead of today. But when I try to load a page, no cookie is actually sent to the server.

This does not happen immediately but after some period of time. I am not sure what more information can be provided here? Please let me know if something else is required to debug the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try cookie domain with dot in it: `.yourdomain.com` In case you're visiting with www, cookies aren't sent if you specified without dot.

Comment: my web.config file has the following information about authentication - 
<forms  loginUrl="Accounts"  defaultUrl="Transactions" name=".ShareBill.Web" timeout="2880" slidingExpiration="true"   >
   </forms>

I have a local deployment  @ localhost and a hosted one @www.sharebill.somee.com.

Comment: should I be settings the "domain name" or "cookie name" in the web.config ?

Comment: nope, in you code: `Response.Cookies("name").Domain = ".yourdomain.com"`

Comment: if the domain is not right then it should not work at all, no? In my case it works initially but after some time even if the expiry date has not reached it does not send the cookie.